# How to return Estimote nearable type in android

Tags: android, estimote

I'm currently working on a project that should return a timestamp,nearable type, nearable id, temperature, proximity, moving/not.

Most of these returns can be found in estimoke.sdk.Nearable, while nearable type is found in cloud.model.nearabletype, though the problem is I don't know how to call it in my code.

I've tried

```
.append("Type: ").append(NearableInfo(NearableType)).append("\n")
```

and

```
.append("Type: ").append(currentNearable.NearableType).append("\n")
```

but both return errors, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearable type is not broadcast in the advertising packet, that's why it's not part of the `Nearable` class.

Instead, type is stored in Estimote Cloud, so you need to use the Estimote SDK to fetch it from there. You can do that via the [`EstimoteCloud#fetchNearableDetails`](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/cloud/EstimoteCloud.html#fetchNearableDetails-java.lang.String-com.estimote.sdk.cloud.CloudCallback-) method. You'll get the `NearableInfo` object in your callback, and that objects has the `type` property which has what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's been wrecking my head all week